# Impresión quitar margen a hoja realizado en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, impresión

Estoy realizando una impresión de un `div` pero al momento que imprimir no se está alineando en el centro de la hoja cuando hace una impresión en una impresora ticket.

Éste es el código que realizo:

```
<script>


         function printDiv(nombreDiv) {
             var contenido = document.getElementById(nombreDiv).innerHTML;
             var contenidoOriginal = document.body.innerHTML;

             document.body.innerHTML = contenido;

             $(nombreDiv).css("media", "print");
             $(nombreDiv).css("background-color", "white");
             $(nombreDiv).css("border-color", "white");
             $(nombreDiv).css("width", "20%");
             $(nombreDiv).css("height", "10%");
             $(nombreDiv).css("white-space", "pre-wrap");
             $(nombreDiv).css("margin", "-23px -40px 0"); /*$("#myPrintArea").css("margin", "-30px -35px 0")*/
             window.print();

             document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
         }


</script>
```

pero al momento de imprimir así, me sale como la imagen de abajo, centrado pero cuando se imprime en el ticket sale más a la derecha y deja un margen a la izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me falta algo?? que tiene que ver vb.net aca?

Comment: @gbianchi hermano era Javascript , me podrias ayudar pf

Comment: @Pierro, puede ser las preferencia de impresión de tu impresora. Revisa el tamaño y demás preferencias.

Comment: Quizá sea porque al imprimir el ticket se toma en cuenta al DOM como  fue cargado en lugar del DOM al ser modificado por JS. Para validar esta hipótesis, haz un HTML estático con los elementos ya colocados tal cual como quieres que aparezcan en tu ticket *e imprímelo*

Comment: O más bien quizá sean tus estilos. Si colocas pixeles en el margin, lo hará tal cual. Prueba con margin: 0 auto; esto debería centrarte el div según el ancho de tu lienzo independientemente de qué ancho sea. No centrará sólo si el ancho del lienzo < width del div

Comment: Si es posible sería bueno que mostraras una foto/imagen de cómo se ve una vez impreso, para ver la diferencia.

Answer (score 1):

Proba poniendolo en una hoja de estilos de esta manera:

> ```
> @media print {
>   #idDiv { 
>     background-colo:white,
>     border-color":white",
>     width:20%,
>     height:10%,
>     white-space: "pre-wrap",
>     margin:-23px -40px 0
>   }
> }
> ```